# Double bonds within cyclopropane ring

Tags: organic-chemistry

With knowledge of ring strain, placing a double bond within a cyclopropane ring would increase the "angle strain" from $109.5 ^\circ$ to $120 ^\circ$ so are cyclopropenes stable? So far, I have only come across the famous aromatic cyclopropene cation but yet to see a neutral cyclopropene ring containing molecule. However, cyclopropanes are quite stable and sometimes occur in nature, so are cyclopropenes well known too?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclopropene

Comment: I see, thank you. Is it possible for these rings to exist in naturally occurring molecules like amino acids?

Comment: "derivatives are known in some fatty acids.".  From the referenced WP article.

Comment: Google sterculic acid.